# Invalidating Amazon CDN using the native API (CreateInvalidation), I'm using TCL language

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation

I'm using AWS CDN service and I linked it with my own origin server. However, I need to build a feature to invalidate the files once the client updates the content. I saw that AWS offers this API

(CreateInvalidation)

```
POST /2019-03-26/distribution/DistributionId/invalidation HTTP/1.1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvalidationBatch xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2019-03-26/">
   <CallerReference>string</CallerReference>
   <Paths>
      <Items>
         <Path>string</Path>
      </Items>
      <Quantity>integer</Quantity>
   </Paths>
</InvalidationBatch>
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CreateInvalidation.html#API_CreateInvalidation_Errors

But I cannot understand how to use it, like what's the distribution URL and what's the date (2019-03-26) is referring to I didn't add any dates in the configuration, I added my **Cname** only.

Also what should be the hostname? is it cloudfront.amazonaws.com? or should I use my **Cname**

Also, what is the xmlns?? Is it the directory path which contains the files I need to invalidate?

And they are not mentioning any thing about the authorization, shouldn't I be using the secret key and the access key?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

> But I cannot understand how to use it, like what's the distribution URL and what's the date (2019-03-26) is referring to I didn't add any dates in the configuration, I added my Cname only.

Most of the path is static (the date is for example simply the version of the API). You only have to replace "DistributionId" with your distribution-id, which you find in the distribution-details in your AWS console.

> Also what should be the hostname? is it cloudfront.amazonaws.com? or should I use my Cname

Yes, the hostname is "cloudfront.amazonaws.com", because this is the API endpoint of CloudFront: [Amazon CloudFront endpoints and quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/cf_region.html)

> Also, what is the xmlns?? Is it the directory path which contains the files I need to invalidate?

The xmlns is just meta-information about the xml itself, you can ignore that.

You will have to declare paths to invalidate though, this the "string" value in "<Path>string</Path>". For every path you want to invalidate you have to add another "<Path>string</Path>". The syntax is documented here: [Specifying the Files to Invalidate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidation-specifying-objects). You will also need to replace "integer" with the amount of paths you configured in "<Quantity>integer</Quantity>".

And finally you have to replace "string" in "<CallerReference>string</CallerReference>" with a unique value with each call, CloudFront will ignore a call where it received the CallerReference already.

> And they are not mentioning any thing about the authorization, shouldn't I be using the secret key and the access key?

Yes, but this will not be part of the body of the request, but of the headers. See this page (and its sub-pages) on how to do that: [Signing AWS API requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html)

Comment: Thanks Christian. this is very helpful.